# Testing Recurring payment in paypal sandbox

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated paypal sandbox but how can i use paypal recurring payment procedure. which parameter is required for recurring and how can i use web hook for recurring.If any suggest me how to use paypal sandbox recurring and provide best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Which type of recurring is being used?

1. If you are implementing recurring using NVP/SOAP API, kindly refer to the below. Kindly note that webhook is not compatible with NVP/SOAP API
   a. Using Express Checkout - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile_API_Operation_NVP/

   b. Using PayPal buttons- https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/button-manager/BMCreateButton_API_Operation_NVP/

for notifications, you can use IPN to get notifications every time a payment is made

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/

2. If you are implementing using REST API, webhook is used for receiving notifications. Refer to the links below
   a. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments.billing-agreements
   b. https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/webhooks/